# Yarn kills container when number of tasks > number of executors

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I have a spark program, which runs perfectly fine when number of tasks = number of executors with a given executor memory. But if the number of tasks is greater than the number of executors, I get the following error on the second round.

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 16.0 GB of 16 GB physical memory used. 
Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

By the second round, I mean that an executor executes its first task perfectly fine, but as soon as it starts executing the second task given to it, yarn kills it. When yarn kills the container (executor), a new container (executor) is spawned obviously, and this time again the excecutor executes the task given to it fine, but fails on the second task. The input data corresponding to each task is almost the same, so the memory requirements must also be the same. But anyway, the problem occurs no matter how much I increase the executor's memory. I also made sure I closed all the resources properly in my program. So, what could be the possible reason of this very annoying problem?

P.S: I also tried to increase `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`, but that didn't solve the problem either.